# How to fold for, while and if blocks in Java Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, folding, code-folding

I'm using Eclipse Luna for Java. By default, Eclipse only lets me fold Comments, Header Comments, Inner Types, Members and Imports.

Is there a plugin that allows me to fold **for**, **while** and **if** blocks?

I searched the marketplace and various sources and found nothing for this.

Edit: Before downvoting, consider I have thoroughly researched this before posting. Other similar questions on the site don't solve this problem or are completely outdated and resources no longer available. Also, I'm not looking for a #beginregion #endregion workaround (the code is already written and that's not really a good solution).

Comment: Check this answer [Is there a way to fold eclipse sub-blocks like an "if" statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369057/is-there-a-way-to-fold-eclipse-sub-blocks-like-an-if-statement)

Comment: I have. That question is from 2010 and all the resources are unavailable. I have looked at all related questions in the site before posting. (Also, I don't know if you were the one to downvote me, but if you did it's really unfair.)

Comment: so you must add this info in your question!!!

Comment: I thought it was expected to have researched the question before posting. I quote "I searched the marketplace and various sources and found nothing for this". And you sent me to a 5 year old post with broken links and downvote me for having done my research properly?

Comment: **first** I didn't downvote I flagged question to be closed **second** I don't know if you make any research, I'm not a sorcerer **third** http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask **fourth** in this way you won't get much help in SO

Comment: I don't mean to be rude. It's just I asked a pertinent question and I keep getting downvoted. It's very frustrating. Can you deflag me?

Comment: sure, but when you update your question with the info of your research... please take a look to link of how to ask, just in first point says: ***Search**, and research
...and keep track of what you find. Even if you don't find a useful answer elsewhere on the site, including links to related questions that haven't helped*

Comment: if you searched... why you dont finished [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940199/how-to-use-coffee-bytes-code-folding/6947590#6947590) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534542/what-code-folding-plugins-work-on-eclipse-3-6/8706723#8706723) or [here](http://themindstorms.blogspot.com.es/2006/11/my-eclipse-code-folding-plugin.html)???? all the links appear in the question i linked....

Comment: I've seen all of those links and none of them have folding for if, for or while blocks. Only user defined regions. And yes, I should've linked the similar questions that didn't help.

Comment: It appears to me that the question linked by @JordiCastilla has an answer. It's just not the answer that you hoped for (no, sorry, no support and no plug-in).

Answer (score 2):

Try using the Coffee Bytes plugin.

the archive and installation instructions can be found at [this blogspot](http://kosiara87.blogspot.com/2011/12/how-to-install-coffee-bytes-plugin-in.html).

Alternately, [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/specials/idea/idea.jsp?gclid=Cj0KEQjw7_mrBRDH4Y2UjLHEmfcBEiQA8OTHf8LKzYhVBC8_ShMzNWDYXKJoq4b4e8jwodsJgfyfizEaAjRX8P8HAQ) supports folding all blocks surrounded by brackets e.g.{}.

Comment: be careful... this blogspot is same url of question I linked!!! he was quite angry with that ;)

Comment: I've checked your link and noticed that the blogspot link in that question was in an answer other than the accepted one. Perhaps this made it difficult to locate? The same link is definitely there though and I have confirmed **it is not broken**. @user1766833 if Jordi answers the question with the link, I recommend you accept his answer. That is if the coffee bytes plugin actually solves the issue

Comment: don't worry, I won't post any answer... but is nice OP realizes the lack of research that denotes the question in order to ask better ones in the future....

Comment: Thanks LanguidSquid, but that plugin is only for regions (#beginregion #endregion) and not for for, while, if, else blocks. Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: If you are willing to switch, I know that **IntelliJ IDEA** supports code folding

Comment: please dont cross read.... http://stackoverflow.com/a/6947590/3850595

Comment: Also, if Jordi answers the question with an answer that solves my problem, I will gladly accept. (What's cross read?)