# Coffee-Bytes code folding with Eclipse Neon

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am using Eclipse-Neon on MacOSX 10.12. I would like to use the Coffee-Bytes plugin.

I have read and tried the advice in

[is-there-a-way-to-fold-eclipse-sub-blocks-like-an-if-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369057/is-there-a-way-to-fold-eclipse-sub-blocks-like-an-if-statement),

[how-to-fold-for-while-and-if-blocks-in-java-eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30848612/how-to-fold-for-while-and-if-blocks-in-java-eclipse),

[how-to-use-coffee-bytes-code-folding/6947590#6947590](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940199/how-to-use-coffee-bytes-code-folding/6947590#6947590)

as well as the blogspot [how-to-install-coffee-bytes-plugin-in](http://kosiara87.blogspot.de/2011/12/how-to-install-coffee-bytes-plugin-in.html)

However, for the installation I cannot find the features folder. In my installation folder for Eclipse:

```
/Applications/java-neon/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse
```

there are only the folders configuration, dropins, plugins, readme. I read this article [eclipse-plugins-vs-features-vs-dropins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763843/eclipse-plugins-vs-features-vs-dropins) and naively installed the Coffe-Bytes features content into the dropins folder of my Eclipse installation and the Coffe-Bytes plugins into the plugins folder of my Eclipse installation. 
Restarted Eclipse, went to Preferences->Java->Editor->Folding, but did not see the GUI schema found in the 3rd reference above. Instead I see the schema as [image: Eclipse Neon schema].

Can someone inform me if I have done something incorrectly, or is Coffee-Bytes not compatible with Eclipse-Neon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I don't have access/ability to test this at the moment, but it should work like this. Please feel free to write your own answer if you get to a solution that is not as I have outlined.)

Unzip the offline installer, you should end up with something like this:

```
offline.zip
offline_unzipped_name/
   features/
       feature.jar (may be more than one)
   plugins/
       plunin.jar (may be more than one)
```

Copy the `offline_unzipped_name` folder in its entirety to the `dropins/` folder in Eclipse.

However you should (if possible) always install new software into Eclipse with the *Install New Software* menu item. This will ensure that the plug-ins have all their required dependencies.

Of course as the link you have provided is ~5 years old, it could be that the plug-ins themselves simply don't work with Neon as you suggested.

Comment: It was how you suggested. However, there was a caveat. The Install New Software would not allow me to install it. The featured appeared after I restarted Eclipse.

Comment: Glad it worked. The coffee bytes zip file does not have the necessary bits to allow being installed with the install new software method. I suppose the "if possible" is directed as much at plug-in suppliers as users.